# VScode でPowershell デバッグとpythonデバッグを共存させる方法

Tags: python, vscode, powershell, debugging

## 環境

- Window10 pro
- VScode 1.70.2
- python venvによる仮想環境　/ENVフォルダ下にPython 3.9.10 <- pythonインタプリタ選択済み
- Powershell Extension v2022.7.2
- VScode拡張機能
  　PowerShell
  　Python
  　Python Extended
  　Python Extension Pack
  　Python Docs
  Code Runner
  ..etc

## 目的

普段は、Pythonでの開発なので、F5デバッグ実行はPython仮想環境下にあるPythonが実行されます。
Powershellスクリプト によるドキュメント作成自動化なども行います。Powershellスクリプトの実行にはCodeRunnerを使用していましたが、今まで動作していたスクリプトが何らかの要因でエラーが発生してしまい、デバッグして追いかけたいと思いました。
しかし、Powershellスクリプトを開き、カレントファイルとして、[実行]->[デバッグ開始]をすると、Pythonスクリプトとして実行しようとしてしまいます。

実行時ターミナルの様子

```
(ENV) PS [カレントフォルダ]> c:; cd '[カレントフォルダ]'; & '[カレントフォルダ]\ENV\Script\python.exe' '[(省略)..\pythonFiles\lib\debugpy\adpter/../..\debugpy\launcher]' '55292' '--' '[カレントファイル]'
```

上記の[カレントファイル]は、この場合、ps1ファイルとなります。

・ps1ファイルを判断して、Powershellデバッグ実行
・pyファイルを判断して、Pythonデバッグ実行
という環境にできないかという相談です。

### launch.json

```
{
    // IntelliSense を使用して利用可能な属性を学べます。
    // 既存の属性の説明をホバーして表示します。
    // 詳細情報は次を確認してください: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

### setting.json

```
{
  "esbonio.server.enabled": true,
  "esbonio.sphinx.confDir": "",
  "restructuredtext.preview.name": "docutils",
  "files.encoding": "utf8bom"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershellをごくまれにしか使わないならば、`launch.json`にPowershellの構成を追加して`launch.json画面左上の「実行とデバッグ」右のコンボボックスから選択する方法がシンプルだと思います。

拡張子で自動的にファイル判別をする場合は[Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable)拡張機能を使うことで実現可能です。
下記の`launch.json`例では、画面左上の「実行とデバッグ」右のコンボボックスから「Debug Python or Powershell」を選択すると`.ps1`と`.py`を自動判別実行できます。
ただしターミナルの表示が自動的に切り替わってくれないので、画面右下の縦タブから手動で切り替えを行う必要があります。

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File if .py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${input:file_if_python}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        },
        {
            "name": "PowerShell: Current File if .ps1",
            "type": "PowerShell",
            "request": "launch",
            "script": "${input:script_if_powershell}",
            "cwd": "${input:script_if_powershell}" 
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
      {
        "name": "Debug Python or Powershell",
        "configurations": ["Python: Current File if .py", "PowerShell: Current File if .ps1"]
      }
    ],
    "inputs": [
      {
        "id": "file_if_python",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
        "args": {
          ".py": "${file}",
          ".ps1": "${workspaceFolder}\\.vscode\\dummy" 
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "script_if_powershell",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
        "args": {
          ".ps1": "${file}",
          ".py": "${workspaceFolder}\\.vscode\\dummy" 
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

[image: スクリーンショット]

**参考資料**

- [Define multiple launch configurations in VS Code basing on file extensionの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64601770)
- [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable)
- [Debugging in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)